# How to find this $x$, given $\frac{1}{6!} +\frac{1}{7!} = \frac{x}{8!}.$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{1}{6!} +\frac{1}{7!} = \frac{x}{8!}.$$

Comment: Hi! What have you tried as of yet? As an aside, please consider using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it makes it easier for others to read :)

Comment: Where could you possibly have found any difficulty here?  Voting to close.

Comment: yep okhe fine..

Comment: It's a simple linear equation with one variable. I'm sure you can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do u know that $n!\cdot(n+1)=(n+1)! $

Just keep multiplying and dividing by a number that you require in denominator.

$\frac{1}{6!} +\frac{1}{7!} $ can be written as $\frac{1\cdot 7}{6!\cdot7} +\frac{1}{7!} $
which becomes $\frac{7}{7!} +\frac{1}{7!} =\frac{8}{7!} $

Again write $\frac{8}{7!} $ as $\frac{8\cdot 8}{7!\cdot 8} $
This becomes: $\frac{64}{8!} $
So, $x=64$

Comment: You shouldn't use * as multiplication. Use \cdot instead. Also, if you want to write something in proper formatting, cover the **whole** expression with dollar signs

Comment: ya, thanks for that...was in search for its syntax this long.

Answer (score 2):

Find the LCD and proceed from there.

$$\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{1}{7!} = \frac{x}{8!}$$

$$8! = 6!(7)(8) = 7!(8)$$

$$\frac{7(8)}{8!}+\frac{8}{8!} = \frac{x}{8!}$$

Now, just ignore the denominators.

$$56+8 = x \implies x = 64$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\dfrac{1}{6!} +\dfrac{1}{7!} = \dfrac{x}{8!} \iff 8!\dfrac{1}{6!} +8!\dfrac{1}{7!} = 8!\dfrac{x}{8!} \iff x=8\cdot 7+8=64$$