# SyberMath's quick and easy factorial problem from 3 days ago on Youtube

Tags: solution-verification, factorial

$\color{white}{\require{\cancel}{3}}$

So I was scrolling through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I would think that I could solve, when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/VGJZfv_P6ko) supposedly easy factorial problem by SyberMath:$$\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{1}{7!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$which I wanted to try and solve on my own. Here are my steps that I took to get my solution:$$\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{1}{7!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$$$\implies\frac{7!}{6!7!}+\frac{6!}{6!7!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$$$\iff\frac{6!+7!}{6!7!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$$$\iff\frac{6!+7!}{10!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$$$\implies\frac{6!8!+7!8!}{8!10!}=\frac{10!x}{8!10!}$$$$\implies\frac{6!8!+7!8!-10!x}{8!10!}=0$$$$\implies\frac{6!\cancel{8!}+7!\cancel{8!}-\cancel{10!}x}{\cancel{8!}\cancel{10!}}=0$$$$\iff\frac{6!}{10!}+\frac{7!}{10!}=\frac{x}{8!}$$$$\iff\frac{6!8!+7!8!}{10!}=x$$$$\iff64=x$$**My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or if I am not, what steps can I take to more easily attain the correct solution?

Comment: Your solution is correct but a shorter one is to multiply both sides by $8!.$ This way, your equation becomes
$$8\cdot7+8=x$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find this $x$, given $\frac{1}{6!} +\frac{1}{7!} = \frac{x}{8!}.$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933097/how-to-find-this-x-given-frac16-frac17-fracx8)

Comment: (Found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B6!%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B7!%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B8!%7D%24&p=1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just factor it $$\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{1}{7!}=\frac{x}{8!}\Rightarrow\\ \frac{1}{6!}\Big(1+\frac{1}{7}\Big)=\frac{1}{6!}\frac{x}{7\cdot 8}\Rightarrow\\\frac87=\frac{x}{7\cdot 8}\Rightarrow\\64=x$$

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers.

Comment: @AnneBauval Excuse me, what?

Comment: See the link above (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933097)

Comment: @AnneBauval My answer was posted prior to your comment, so why accuse me of duplicating anything?

Comment: I "accuse" you of rushing to answer before looking for duplicates. Anyway, now the search is done so I think you should delete your answer because several identical ones have already be given.

Comment: @AnneBauval Then you are rather quick and eager to accuse me I fear...

Comment: Could we remain factual? Can you please now delete this multiduplicate answer?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake If you are, in fact, using a duplicated answer, then I suggest editing it to make it different from the answer you are duplicating. The fact that I, a ~100 rep user, am telling you, a 5.2K rep user, to edit your post to make it different is just honestly very saddening.

Comment: @AnneBauval Most certainly. I would have no problem deleting my answer or even voting to close the OPs question given that it is a duplicate and of no great mathematical value per se, but I just do not like being falsely (as I perceive it) accused. Anyway..

Comment: Too late now to delete it, unless @CrSb0001 unaccepts it.

Comment: @CrSb0001 This is frankly ridiculous. I didn't replicate any answer, nor was I aware it was asked before. I just posted what directly came to mind when I saw your problem... I am out...

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I'm not saying you did. All I'm saying is if near-identical versions *of your answer* exists, then why not just *edit the question* to make it less nearly identical to the answers that are showing up as identical/similar to your answer

Comment: @CrSb0001 Did you bother to check or compare my answer and the "duplicate"? It just makes use of a simple and direct factorization! Not many ways to present this. What is this all unnecessary drama about?

Comment: @CrSb0001 Can you please unaccept this answer, so that MathematicianByMistake can delete it and we all go to more interesting problems? (I can also delete my prior comment 22 min ago, which was also a duplicate.)