# Evaluation of $\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{2x}}{(x-2)e^{2x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{2x}}{(x-2)e^{2x}}$$
I tried solving this limit using some standard limit methods but could not come to a successful conclusion.

I would be highly obliged if the respected community provides me with some help. Thank you!

Comment: Please include your attempts, even if they failed. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683134/sybermaths-quick-and-easy-factorial-problem-from-3-days-ago-on-youtube/4683139?noredirect=1#comment9903979_4683139

Comment: The limit looks to be the derivative at $2$ of the map $x \mapsto e^{x^2-2x}$. And therefore exists and is equal to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that :
$$\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{2x}}{(x-2)e^{2x}}=\frac{e^{x^2-2x}-1}{x-2}
$$
And therfore:
$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{2x}}{(x-2)e^{2x}}=\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2-2x}-1}{x-2}
$$
using L'hopital
then
$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2-2x}-1}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to2} \frac{(2x-2)e^{x^2-2x}}{1}=2$$

Finally :
$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{2x}}{(x-2)e^{2x}}=2$$